# Como Se conectan a mi aplicacion via internet sin estar en la red lan

Tags: python-2.7

Hola Estoy Haciendo Una aplicacion en python es con sockets , Como hago para que otra persona que no este en la red lan (este en internet) se conecte a mi aplicacion en el puerto espeficicado???he buscado y he encontrado que se usa ssh, nat y que tengo que tener una ip estatica pero no se aun ?????

Answer (score 2):

Eee pues la realmente esa etiqueta no corresponde a tu pregunta. Pero igual lo que tienes que hacer es un PorForwarding desde router o modem que te provee el internet.

Simplemente lo que se hace con esto es que un puerto de cara a internet de tu router redirije todo el trafico hacia una direccion ip de la red local que tu especifiques.